# Android BottomSheet covers half of anchored ImageView

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I have a `CoordinatorLayout` in which I have a `BottomSheet` and an `ImageView`.

This is my **BottomSheett**:

```
<include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_layout"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"/>
```

And this my **ImageView**:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_location_crosshairs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_sheet"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_svg_icon"/>
```

Regardless of the view order in my XML layout, I always get the same result: my ImageView is nicely anchored to the bottomsheet, but the anchor takes place at the center of my image.

I would like to know how can I have my image bottom being anchored instead of its center.
Trying to apply any kind of bottom margin will only have the bottomsheet slide until reaching center of image before making the image slides as well.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an empty `View`, with `layout_height` and `layout_width` set to `wrap_content`.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And then link this empty View to the `BottomSheet`.

Comment: You meant to say that I should add this view to my `BottomSheet`, make it fully transparent, with a height in order to fake a margin equivalent to the half the height of my `ImageView` ? Visually speaking that could work. Better, I guess, than my current solution using padding. But too hacky still. I thought there was something in the API... Thanks, I'll try your solution ;-)

Comment: Yeah. You don't need to make it invisible. It won't take any space in your layout, it'd be just there without disturbing anything. Same kinda thing is used to space out things evenly in LinearLayout when layout_weight is specified. You put an empty View wherever you want!

Comment: Alright, thanks. I went even further. I wrapped my `ImageView` into a simple `FrameLayout` with `wrap_content` for h&w. Using bottom margin inside for my image did the trick and is much cleaner than using padding. Especially since I intend to listen to click events on that image!! It feel less hacky that way. I'll validate your solution but people should read our comments. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Bottom margin will work, but what if it's a tablet? What if the orientation is changed? Did you check that? Put your device on landscape orientation and check if the margin worked? I'm pretty sure your layout will look messed up!

Comment: Works in landscape, but not intended usage. Landscape is allowed for now on my project.